# How to add html5 placeholder attribute to form input elements in Spring MVC

Tags: html, spring-mvc, dojo, spring-webflow

How to add html5 placeholder attribute to form input elements in Spring MVC?

Example:

```
<input type="text" required="true" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder="Your Name" 
                dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" missingMessage="Ooops!  You forgot your first name!" />
```

Comment: Is your example Spring MVC code?  If so, it looks like it works already.  If not, post the actual code you've tried.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

Use camelCasing the 'placeholder' into 'placeHolder'. 
Programmatic:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    var inp = new dijit.form.TextBox({
        placeHolder: 'Your Name',
        name: 'firstName',
        id:'firstName'
    });
    dojo.byId('placeHolderNode').appendChild(inp.domNode);
});​
```

Declarative:

```
 <input type="text" required="true" name="firstName" id="firstName" 

       placeHolder="Your Name" 

            dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" missingMessage="Ooops!  You forgot your first name!" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/G6VYA/1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell dojo (1.9 checked) does not use html5 placeholders but creates a span to hold the placeholder text.  The dojo documentation states:

> Coming with Dojo 1.5 the HTML5 placeholder parameter (also known as a
>   “hint”) has been implemented for all TextBox based widgets.
>   Placeholder is gray example or hint text that the widget displays
>   inside the input area of empty form fields, such as “John Doe” or
>   “Your Name”. The text disappears when the user focuses the field.

This is inaccurate, the generated code has no html5 markup.  I wish it did.